# What's the best way to let a JSF view generate a response to a non-jsf request?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

I have a servlet which is in the same web application as the JSF servlet.
How do I replace (rather than redirect) the servlet response with the JSF response?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand your question - but if you want to include the output from a JSF page in your servlet response, something like:

```
public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Do stuff
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/blah.jsf").forward(req, res);
        // Do other stuff
}
```

Should do the trick

Comment: You can extend javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet and make use of the HTTP methods(doGet(), doPost() etc) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [urlrewritefilter](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/index.html).

Simple

```
    <rule>
        <from>^/my/servlet/uri</from>
        <to>/jsfpage.jsf</to>
    </rule>
```

should be enough.